# Jquery draggable + resizable element going out of bounds

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

An element which is has the resizable and draggable Jquery plugin applied to it is going out of bounds if the parent element doesn't have

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Applied to it.

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/

Try dragging the element to the far most bottom right corner a couple of times. You will see that it is going out of bounds. I figured out that if i set the parent element e.g. #outer to overflow:hidden that the problem is solved.

**The problem:**
I need the parent to have overflow:visible for other CSS to work fine. How else can i resolved the problem *without* making the parent overflow:hidden?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't go out of bounds with me, only when you resize it in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: I just tested it. In opera not, but in IE and chrome it does :( When it's already in the bottom right corner and you drag it again, that's when the problem occurs.

Comment: Now I see! It only happens, if the block has NOT been resized. I resized it before dragging it... Is this jFiddle only or live as well?

Comment: if you put it in bottom right corner. Release the mouse click and click and drag again, you can drag it about 3px. If you release again and click and drag it will move about 3px again. So you can pretty much drag it how far you want. Maybe something you should report to the jQuery team?

Comment: Yeah I will. I was wandering if it was a problem with my code or if it's a glitch :)

Comment: Yeah, I would also suggest this is a bug. I tried putting `.resizable()` after the `.draggable()`, but that didn't help. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resizable transforms the element to be absolutely positioned, so the bounding box is irrelevant,

There seems  to be a bug, that you can drag 3px out of the bounding box, so replace your fiddle with this code which adds a 3px snap function so you can't drag 3px out of the boundary :-)

```
$(function(){
    $('#inner').resizable({
        containment: 'parent'        
        }).draggable({
        containment: 'parent' ,
        snap: "#outer", snapMode: "inner" ,
        snapTolerance: 3       
    });    
});​
```

You need overflow visible! when the item draggable and resizable, otherwise I found that it caused the item to be irretrievable!

Comment: Webestdesigns. Could you explain your code? Maybe include it in my JSfiddle? As I have no idea how this solves my problem, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you're using a different browser, but with chrome, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't resize the element, and keep dragging it far bottom right. You will see the problem is not solved :(

Answer (score 1):

My solution for anyone it helps, working code in the fiddle

```
$('#box-1').draggable({
  grid: [20, 10],
  axis: "x",
  containment: '#container'
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjasv3hg/